# ¿Cómo quitar el salto de línea en pantalla al hacer un print dentro de un for in?

Tags: python

Mi código es:

```py
import msvcrt, random

cuanto = int(input("Ponga los numeros de los caracteres: "))

for x in range(cuanto):
    x = random.randint(0,9)
    print(x)
```

y mi problema es que no sé cómo hacer que se pongan en la misma línea: al ejecutarlo sale un número debajo del otro.

Comment: `print(x)` siempre agrega un `\n` al final.  Si usas `end="cadena"`, en lugar de agregar un `\n`, el `print()` agrega la cadena que indicas, que puede ser cualquier cosa, cualquier largo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo como hacer una variable externa.

```
import msvcrt, random

cuanto = int(input("Ponga los numeros de los caracteres: "))

cadena=""
for x in range(cuanto):
    cadena= cadena + str(random.randint(0,9))
print(cadena)
```

también lo puedes hacer con el `for` en una sola línea, aunque imprimirías una lista:

```
import msvcrt, random

cuanto = int(input("Ponga los numeros de los caracteres: "))

print([random.randint(0,9) for x in range(cuanto)])
```

Otra alternativa seria usar el argumento `end` en `print`, `end` lo que hace es que al acabar de imprimir algo imprima lo guardado en el argumento `end` si el siguiente `print` tambien lo lleva imprimirá lo guardado en su `end`, por default `end` es un salto de línea, es decir  `\n`, la solución seria la siguiente:

```
import msvcrt, random

cuanto = int(input("Ponga los numeros de los caracteres: "))

for x in range(cuanto):
    x = random.randint(0,9)
    print(x, end=" ")#si no pones espacio quedaría 123456
```

Hay infinitas formas, me parece una pregunta simple, creo que no has buscado suficiente o no has pensado mucho. No importa, pero procura informarte antes de hacer una pregunta. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: otra forma `print(" ".join([random.randint(0,9) for x in range(cuanto)]))`

Comment: @Christian como dije hay infinitas formas puse solo las más simples (sin métodos, ni demasiados paréntesis...)para no liar mucho, aun así es muy buena alternativa.

Comment: @Christian en lugar de envolver una comprensión de lista, con "  ".join, por que no usas comprensión de generador (quitando los corchetes)?

Comment: @DanteS. cierto, he andado un poco alejado de python últimamente.

Comment: Pues bienvenido de vuelta entonces :D

Answer (score 3):

Hola si lo que quieres es poner los numero uno en frente del otro asi "1 2 3 4 ...", puedes dejar tu codigo asi:

```
import msvcrt, random

cuanto = int(input("Ponga los numeros de los caracteres: "))

for x in range(cuanto):
    x = random.randint(0,9)
    print(x, end=" ")
```

Comment: Explica el uso de `end=`.

Comment: @Candid Moe ya vi bien xd, el end sirve para ver como quedara el final, osea el end por defecto en un for en int es "\n" que significa salto de linea, pero si lo cambias por " " no se saltara la linea

Comment: @UnHUmano no solo en el `for int` siempre es por defecto `\n`. Por ejemplo seria lo mismo `print("Algo\n", end="")` que `print("Algo")`